# looping over each column to impute data in R but does not replace imputed data

Tags: r, loops, hmisc, imputation

I am trying to impute the dataframe with Hmisc impute model. I am able to impute the data for one column at a time but fail to loop over columns.

Below example - works fine but I would like to make it dynamic using a function:

```
impute_marks$col1 <- with(impute_marks, round(impute(col1, mean)),0)
```

Example:

```
impute_dataframe <- function()
{
  for(i in 1:ncol(impute_marks))
  {
    impute_marks[is.na(impute_marks[,i]), i] <- with(impute_marks, round(impute(impute_marks[,i], mean)),0)
  }
}
impute_dataframe
```

There is no error when I run the function but there is no imputed data as well to the dataset impute_marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hmisc::impute` is already a function, why not just use `apply` and save a `for` loop?:

```
library(Hmisc)
age1 <- c(1,2,NA,4)
age2 <- c(NA, 4, 3, 1)
mydf <- data.frame(age1, age2)

mydf
  age1 age2
1    1   NA
2    2    4
3   NA    3
4    4    1

apply(mydf, 2, function(x) {round(impute(x, mean))})
  age1 age2
1    1    3
2    2    4
3    2    3
4    4    1
```

EDIT: To keep `mydf` as a data.frame you could coherce it back like this:

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(mydf)
```

But what I'd do is use another package `purrr` which is nice set of tools around this apply/mapping idea. `map_df` for example will always return a `data.frame` object, there are a bunch of `map_x` that you can see with `?map`

```
library(purrr)
map_df(mydf, ~ round(impute(., mean)))
```

I know it is preferred to use the base R functions, but `purrr` makes `apply` style operations so much easier.

Comment: I am fairly new to R. I wasnt aware of apply function. Thanks for pointing it out. I was able to achieve what I wanted but I get a matrix rather than a data frame at the end of the operation. How can I convert it to data frame after imputing. this is what i got: num[1:153, 1:26] 55 68 .... all the values. rather than 153 obs. 26 variables

Comment: I got it resolved by wrapping whole right hand side using as.data.frame()

Comment: if you find yourself doing this a lot, check out `library(purrr)` it has nice syntax and I think it is more intuitive than the base `apply`, `lapply` , etc functions

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.aggregate` from `zoo` which can be applied directly on the dataset

```
library(zoo)
round(na.aggregate(mydf))
#  age1 age2
#1    1    3
#2    2    4
#3    2    3
#4    4    1
```

or in each column separately with `lapply`

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) round(na.aggregate(x)))
```

By default, `na.aggregate` gives the `mean`.  But, we can change the `FUN`